# My profile picture is coming back with parameters with Javascript SDK open graph api. How can I get a straight url that ends in .JPG?

Tags: javascript, facebook, image, jpeg, profile

[https://fbcdn-profile-a.akamaihd.net/hprofile-ak-xpa1/v/t1.0-1/c134.0.533.533/10388198_10152483707319663_1667528218431077014_n.jpg?oh=2ef7e4b17679e0c9776ddf1162dc035d&oe=54547985&**gda**=1414486082_14ab063b547235d9c3badae01a0f6e9d](https://fbcdn-profile-a.akamaihd.net/hprofile-ak-xpa1/v/t1.0-1/c134.0.533.533/10388198_10152483707319663_1667528218431077014_n.jpg?oh=2ef7e4b17679e0c9776ddf1162dc035d&oe=54547985&__gda__=1414486082_14ab063b547235d9c3badae01a0f6e9d)

The parameters wil not allow me to load the image in a flash component. I need to hit a clean URL with no parameters. When I remove the parameters it says an error has occurred. I have noticed this "?oh=" parameter in photos a person has been tagged in as well. I am using cross domain.xml to have permission. I have logged in with other developer accounts and their images load.

Thanks!
GJ

Comment: What do you mean that you use a crossdomain.xml to be able to load it? akamaihd.net needs a crossdomain.xml file for you to be able to load it.

Comment: Flash has security settings when loading an image from a different domain. You need to load the cross domain.xml file from the domain you are fulling images from to give flash permission to load it. If the image was on your same domain you do not need to do this. I just want to let people know that it is not security settings causing my problem. My issue is that my link is not a raw .jpg file at a URL. The parameters are messing up Flash's image loader. I am wondering how I can get a clean URL? Thanks!

Comment: I faced the same your issue @GeoffJordan. Have you found any solution ?

Answer (score 0):

The issue was actually a problem with flashvars... Um yeah I needed to URL encode the & sign with javascript and then decode it back in Flash to pull the image.... Cheers